# How should I approach the implementation of this C if statement given the requirements?

Tags: c

I am currently attempting to create a source code that meets these following requirements:

Requirements:

// Get a deep copy of a portion of array from index first to index last

// inclusive. If successful, return a pointer to a newly-allocated intarr_t containing a copy of the specfied section.

**// If an error occurs, i.e. array is null, first or last are out of bounds, last < first, or memory allocation fails, return a null pointer.**

I have completed the first two requirements, but it seems that my logic for the third one is faulty, and no matter how much I test it, I can't seem to find the corner case that occurs.

My code:

```
intarr_t* intarr_copy_subarray( intarr_t* array, 
                unsigned int first, 
                unsigned int last )
{
    intarr_t *tmp;
    tmp = malloc((last-first)*sizeof(intarr_t));
    // it seems that my if statement is not meeting the requirement in bold.
    if(first>=0 && last<= array->len && array != NULL && first > last && tmp != NULL)
    {
        //perform copying here
        return tmp; // pointer to new array containing the copied stuff
    }
    else
    {
        return NULL;
    }
}

typedef struct {
  int* data;
  unsigned int len;
} intarr_t;
```

There seems to be a case where it returns NULL when it is not supposed to and it has to do with my if statement. Note that I am passing my function a typedef structure that contains a pointer to an array and the length, but that isn't the problem. Should I be using OR statements rather than AND statements?

Comment: Show the definition of intarr_t.

Comment: Okay, one second please.

Comment: If last < first, what size are you trying to malloc?

Comment: Okay, I added it in the end of my following code, perhaps my problem is that I am using AND statements which only evaluate true if all are logic 1. Should be OR statement I suppose?

Comment: I made it so that first was greater than last because first is the starting index, and it wouldn't make sense to ahve the first index you want to copy to be greater than the ending index?

Comment: You really should test your requirements before allocating new memory. If that can't be done, `free` the memory you already allocated before returning `NULL`. I doubt that you have completed the first two requirements. You have only allocated memory that most likely contains garbage. You still have some actual copying to do. We don't know about your `inrarray_t` type, but a "deep" copy of an array means that the objects in an array are copied, too. (As opposed to a "shallow" copy, where only references, i.e. pointers are copied.)

Comment: You have `... && first > last && ...`.  You want `... && first <= last && ...`

Comment: If it helps: You don't have to write all requirements in one big condition. You can process them one by one: `if (first < 0) return NULL; if (last < first) return NULL;` etc.

Comment: @user152573 Where are you hurry? See my answer.:)

Comment: this line: tmp = malloc((last-first)*sizeof(intarr_t)); should be: tmp = malloc((last-first+1)*sizeof(intarr_t)); otherwise the malloc'd area will be one intarr_t size short

Comment: the code should NOT perform the malloc operation until the parameters to the function are validated.  suggest: perform each validation step individually, and if ALL the steps pass, then perform the malloc and associated check of the returned value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function can look like

```
intarr_t* intarr_copy_subarray( const intarr_t *array, 
                                unsigned int first, 
                                unsigned int last )
{
    if ( array == NULL || array->data == NULL || last < first || array->len <= last )
    {
        return NULL;
    }    

    intarr_t *tmp = malloc( sizeof( intarr_t ) );

    if ( tmp )
    {
        tmp->data = malloc( ( last - first + 1 ) * sizeof( int ) );
        if ( tmp->data == NULL )
        {
            free( tmp );
            tmp = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            tmp->len = last - first + 1;
            for ( unsigned int i = 0; i < tmp->len; i++ ) 
            {
                tmp->data[i] = array->data[first + i];
            }
        }
    }

    return tmp;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for response, I wish I could check mark both answers, but I can't..It seems that my guess was correct to change my && to || because we want it to evaluate to logic 1 whenver the conditions are 1 and the rest 0.

Comment: @user152573  See how I am freeing tmp if tmp->data was not allocated. In fact it is a ready to use solution.

Comment: I notic eproblem in your if statement, I think we should check if first is greater or equal to 0 because if first is a negative number, then it wouldn't work.

Comment: @user152573 No there is no problem. first has type unsigned int so it in any case is greater than or equal to zero.:) So it is enpugh to check that first is not greater than last.:)

Comment: Ohh, right, I seemed to have conufused it with signed.

Comment: @Serge Ballesta Where is the original data taken? They are copied.

Comment: @Serge Ballesta By the way is it you who down voted my answer thinking that there is no deep copy?:)

Comment: Isn't deep copying in this case just taking the elements in original array and putting it into the new array?

Comment: @user152573 Yse. We allocated a new memory extent and copied where elements of the original object. It is a deep copy.:)

Comment: OKay ahaha.. because I already had the source code to do copying which I made yesterday and I was thinking of doing the pointer thing, but that was too advanced.. I guess I got lucky eh.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow : I did not downvote. And my comment is incorrect. You effectively do a deep copy. But what I understood of the question was that const intarr_t *array pointed to an array of intarr_t. And if it was that, your solution was missing a loop. I did not read it with enough attention and thought you did not copy all.

Comment: WHy is it last - first+1 and not last - first?

Answer (score 1):

First of all check for NULL first:

```
if( !array  )
    return NULL ;
```

Then don't allocate just yet, but check if you arguments are in bounds:

```
if( first>=0 && last< array->len && first <= last )
{
```

Then allocate memory and if successful copy the array to the new subarray.

Your example allocation isn't correct given that `intarr_t` ( _t is a reserved identifier by the way ), holds a pointer to the int array. You should allocate one `intarr_t` and then the array it points to:

```
intarr_t tmp = malloc(sizeof(intarr_t)) ;
if( tmp )
{
     tmp->data = malloc( sizeof( int ) * ( last - first + 1 ) ) ;
     //check if malloc succeeded again
     tmp->len = last - first + 1 ;
     ...
```

Comment: I see, after checking the passed array we can then check if the passed indice are good and then we alloc a new pointer and check if it is NULL and if not we copy.

Comment: For your if statement, I realized that first should be smaller than or equal to last in case we decide to only copy one element i presume?

Comment: @user152573 Well yes, if you copy only one element then first == last.

Comment: Looks like someone beat me to it.